# c# 4.5 - Should a TCP Server, mainly doing database inserts, start each client on a Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, parallel-processing, task

My understanding is that async await is for IO (network, db, etc) and parallel task is for cpu.

*Note: This code is a little harsh to make it concise for this post.*

I have a windows service created in c# that has the following code

```
while (true)
{
    var socket = await tcpListener.AcceptSocketAsync();
    if (socket == null) { break; }

    var client = new RemoteClient(socket);
    Task.Run(() => client.ProcessMessage());
}
```

In the RemoteClient class the ProcessMessage method does this

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
rawMessage = string.Empty;
while (true)
{
    Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    int bytesRead = await networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    rawMessage += (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Replace("\0", string.Empty));

    if (bytesRead == 0 || buffer[buffer.Length - 1] == 0)
    {
        StoreMessage();
        return;
    }
}
```

So I have the I/O work happening asynchronously. But my concern and my question is in using Task.Run to kick off the work am I still creating a block?

I'm trying to take a TCP connection and release it as quickly as possible in order to scale to a large number of connections.

I feel like I'm mixing paradigms here.

Thanks

Comment: Task.Run will create a new task and execute the ProcessMessage. It looks fine and should scale. I am assuming somewhere you are cleaning up the network connections with client.

Comment: @serdevup: Is there any possible way you could self-host SignalR instead of writing your own TCP/IP protocol. Believe me, SignalR is *orders of magnitude* easier, and they've actually designed it *very* well.

Comment: @shr. Thanks for your input. Yes I have handling for close and exception.

Comment: @StephenCleary. Thanks for pointing out SignalIR, I might keep that in mind for other projects. In this instance we are trying to reduce the message size as small as possible and avoid any additional protocols.

Comment: @serdevup: Sorry, I just have to say I really think this is a mistake. And now (early in the project) is the best time to correct it. Writing a proper TCP/IP protocol is non-trivial to say the least. SignalR has a very efficient binary message representation once the HTTP handshake is complete.

Comment: @Stephen. No need to apologize, I do realize the custom TCP is not trivial. We cant afford the HTTP handshake (GET /HTTP/1.1 HOST 123.123.123.123, etc) We did look at this but the smallest header size that could be sent from the client was about 65 bytes, which comes on top of the TCP handshake data.

Comment: @serdevup: Just to be clear, the HTTP handshake is done only once. Once the (single) upgrade request is processed, that connection is converted to a WebSocket connection. All further data is passed only using a fairly efficient binary protocol, and HTTP is no longer used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that async await is for IO (network, db, etc) and parallel task is for cpu.

I would say that understand is incorrect. `async`/`await` is for any asynchronous operation, whether I/O or CPU bound.

> …my concern and my question is in using Task.Run to kick off the work am I still creating a block?

"A block"? What kind of block do you think you would be creating otherwise?

Personally, I would not write the code that way. The `accept` operation will already complete in a thread pool thread (or synchronously in the same thread), i.e. one from the IOCP thread pool. It would be perfectly fine to set up some initial conditions for the connection on that thread, and then initiate the I/O from there. There's no reason to queue up the work on yet another thread.

So the way I'd write the code is like this:

```
async Task ProcessMessage()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    rawMessage = string.Empty;
    while (true)
    {
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        int bytesRead = await networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        rawMessage += (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Replace("\0", string.Empty));

        if (bytesRead == 0 || buffer[buffer.Length - 1] == 0)
        {
            StoreMessage();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your service:

```
while (true)
{
    var socket = await tcpListener.AcceptSocketAsync();
    if (socket == null) { break; }

    var client = new RemoteClient(socket);
    var _ = client.ProcessMessage();
}
```

Notes:

- The dummy `_` variable is just there to keep the compiler from warning you about the ignored, non-awaited async return)
- Since you are ignoring the returned `Task` object, you won't receive thrown exceptions. So in lieu of that, you should add appropriate exception handling to the `ProcessMessage()` method itself.
- I agree with commenter shr regarding cleanup. You didn't provide a complete code example, so we don't know what e.g. the `StoreMessage()` method does. But presumably/hopefully you have logic in there somewhere that correctly and gracefully shuts down the connection and closes the socket.

Comment: Also, AcceptSocketAsync can never return null.

Comment: @usr: yes, correct. That, and the failure to correctly use the `bytesRead` value, were left in to avoid changing more of the original code than was strictly needed to illustrate the answer. Since neither `buffer` nor `rawMessage` appear to actually escape the `ProcessMessage()` method, I am assuming that the full code hasn't really been shared anyway, making it a bit futile to try to suggest other improvements/fixes for the code. I assume the OP will come back with a new question when they find they sometimes close connections having received only partial messages.

Comment: @usr. Thanks both, yeah, I truncated the code to try and make it more concise. The handling of the buffer is a little different to what I use. Thanks very much both for observations.

Comment: @PeterDuniho. Thanks for the detailed response, I can see I was creating an additional thread for no added benefit and it looks a lot cleaner just calling the async method.